latex not finding graphics in wd. using RStudio and r sweave
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{"path to directory"}}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[p]
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=0.9\textwidth]{{"1.png"}}
  \label{092vs326}

\end{figure}


\end{document}

I use RStudio with R sweave and pdflatex to create a big pdf with a lot of pictures and for some reason latex will not find the files in the working directory i set in RStudio. I tried it without the full \graphicspath, ive tried to set the filename in {{}}, in "", tried renaming it, tried to go like {"../folder/filename"} etc. it just cant find it.
This only happens since i accidentially updated RStudio... I tried to recreate all exact steps in setting up my options, but still not working.
Before the update i could include graphics that were created within knitr codechunks directly into my document with no problems.
Any Ideas?

{{"1.png"}}  should be {1.png}

Are you sure you need the pdftex option? In the best case it should be unnecessary, the worst case it will cause trouble if you switch to another engine.

Normally you would just use one of these options width=\linewidth,height=0.9\textwidth  using both will distort the image.

(unrelated to the question, but if you want to use \label, you should add a \caption first so latex has something which it can label)

"tatex will not find the files in the working directory i set in RStudio" Not sure what you mean here, but for LaTeX, the working directory is where it is the .tex version (that is where it is the .Rnw version) and LaTeX doesn't give a damn what you set with the function setwd() in R for  the affairs of R. The command  \graphicspath{} only have sense when the images are NOT in the same folder that the .Rnw text.

thank you Fran, i copied code from another File from another folder and my test .Rnw-file got somehow created there instead of where i wanted it
